# COMFAST CF-WU810NWireless (Realtek 8188EUS) Driver installation

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and need your help with the driver installation of a COMFAST CF-WU810N. The vendor provides a CD with drivers, but when I Use

```
sudo bash install.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
         Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/build M=/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1423:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  daemonize("%s", name);
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1394: recipe for target '_module_/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic'
Makefile:678: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
root@shiv-Inspiron-1545:/home/shiv/Desktop/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222#
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: The circa-2013 file is probably too old to compile in Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a driver this way. Connect to internet an alternative way and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

The first command installs `git` and `dkms` packages.

The second command downloads the driver source from github.

The last two commands install the driver using `dkms`.

Comment: It worked!!. Thanks a lot. can you explain what individual command does?. I tried searching individually but it didnt make any sense to me.